# Using Masonry.js on jQuery generated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I found Masonry.js the other day and wanted to start using it in projects. To practice, I decided that I wanted to try and make a page that would generate 16 divs each time I clicked a button of random heights and colors and watch them position themselves properly. Thing is, it's not working. The divs generate fine, what seems to be the issue is getting Masonry to recalculate the height of the container from the generated divs. Without a height on the container, Masonry cannot calculate the appropriate height for any of the other divs. I've tried using a clearfix on the container to make sure it stretches around the nested elements, but no luck. Can anyone help?

[Check out this Pen of it](http://codepen.io/kyleshevlin/pen/ebguk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use addItems to add items or destroy and recreate to have it recalculate:
http://codepen.io/bhlaird/pen/HusbL

```
//Reload Masonry
$wall.masonry('destroy');
$wall.masonry({
  columnWidth: '.brick',
  itemSelector: '.brick'
});
```

You can also reload and layout:

```
//Reload Masonry
$wall.masonry('reloadItems');
$wall.masonry('layout');
```

Comment: Great answer, both work. The second answer has the interesting effect of generating all the divs at top: 0, left: 0 and then they quickly transition to their location. With the first answer, the divs just appear in their spot. Thank you.